# Git default behavior in merging conflicting branches is just choosing the incoming change without highlighting, have to use --edit, why?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-bash

master branch contents

```
Hello 
Hi
Salut
```

other branch contents

```
Hi
Hey
Yo
```

clearly this should be a conflicting merge in which git should highlight current and incoming change but that's not the case, it says:

```
$ git merge tampering
Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
 greetings.txt | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

when i merge using --edit it highlights normally

```
$ git merge tampering --edit
Auto-merging greetings.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in greetings.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: _Clearly_ is not the right word to use. It all depends on the common ancestor. Just to put up a simple example, if the common ancestor looked like this, there would be no conflict: `Hi\nSalut` (highlighting the EOL with a `\n`). Bottom line: just by looking at the top tips of the 2 branches, you can't _really_ know if there is a conflict (and if there is, you can't know what is coming from each branch). You **need** the common ancestor. What does the common ancestor look like?

Comment: @eftshift0 master was the ancestor of other, to not waste your time I understood my false perception. but i would leave the question and my thought process in case someone also thought this way. thanks though.

Comment: i thought that if there are changes in the same line on two branches (regardless if one is the ancestor of the other) that would be considered a conflicting change but that was wrong since it would be considerd just a fast forward change (not in the simplest way as of adding a new line but fast forward still). A conflicting change could happen if master was changed since the head of master wont be the ancestor of other and thus there would be a common ancestor where other diverged. and that is what @eftshift0 has been asking me about.

Answer (score 0):

In Git, a merge is typically a three-way merge, which considers exactly three points: the two heads, and a point called the merge base, which is usually the common ancestor.

When the merge is performed, if there is a change on one side, but no change on the other, Git adopts the change without even looking at the contents of the file.  (Git can detect this if one side has a blob whose object ID is identical to the merge base and the other does not.)  It sounds like this is what happened in your case, and that's why there was no merge conflict.

Another case in which the same thing happens is when someone makes the same change on both sides of a merge and then reverts one of them.  The reverted side has no change, and therefore, Git adopts the change, whereas most people expect the change to have been reverted.